# NMR spectroscopy nomenclature: induced vs local vs effective magnetic field (B)

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, magnetism

This is a simple question but I can't seem to find a place where they use the same nomenclature... I was wondering whether these are all the same thing: $B_\mathrm{induced}$, $B_\mathrm{local}$, $B_\mathrm{effective}$? I know $B_\mathrm{effective} = B_0 - B_\mathrm{shielding}$. But do all of them mean the same thing (as in the magnetic field felt by the nucleus in a particular environment)? Thank you!

**Edit (including context)**

Context for $B_\mathrm{effective}$:

$\mathrm{\omega}$ = $\mathrm{\gamma}$$B_\mathrm{eff}$ = $\mathrm{\gamma}$$(B_\mathrm{0}-B_\mathrm{shielding})$

I can understand this, but I wanted to know if this $B_\mathrm{eff}$ is the same as induced, and local.

Context for $B_\mathrm{local}$:

[image: B_local]

Context for $B_\mathrm{induced}$

[image: B_ind 1]

[image: B_ind 2]

Thank you!

Comment: +1 Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Please note the edits, we use MathJax to format equations and symbols: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange . I think it might be useful if you could also refer to the context in which $B_\mathrm{induced}$ and $B_\mathrm{local}$ are used.

Comment: The meaning of these words depends upon context. It may help if you could say what you are reading and quote passages where the words are used.

Comment: Agree with above posters - context is required.

Answer (score 5):

In this context, i.e. the discussion of how the chemical shift arises, I'd assume that the *induced* magnetic field is the "internal" magnetic field, which is generated by electrons surrounding the nucleus, in response to the external magnetic field ($B_0$). This induced magnetic field generally serves to oppose the external magnetic field, meaning that the *effective* magnetic field is less than $B_0$. The equation you gave,

$$\omega = \gamma B_\mathrm{eff} = \gamma(B_0 - B_\mathrm{shielding})$$

suggests that $B_\mathrm{shielding}$ is to be identified with the induced magnetic field and that $B_\mathrm{eff}$ is what's left after removing that.

Note, however, that $B_\mathrm{eff}$ may mean something else in a different context (e.g. when discussing the vector model of NMR).

On the other hand, $B_\mathrm{local}$ is being used in a completely different scenario, namely that of nuclear spin relaxation. It refers to a magnetic field generated at the location of one nucleus due to other nuclei. (Think of every nucleus, or every NMR-active nucleus at least, being a bar magnet — $B_\mathrm{local}$ is the magnetic field generated by these bar magnets.)

This is in contrast to $B_\mathrm{shielding}$ above, which is generated by electrons around the nucleus of interest.

So none of them are the same.